# How load jQuery plugin directive after ng-repeat data loaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS and trying to make tags manager directive with http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager. Problem is, when jQuery plugin is called, tags input and name input doesn't have {{index}} value yet. How could I fix it?

My HTML code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(index, title) in shop.locales"  style="position: relative">  
    <span> {{ title }}</span>  
    <div class="input-block">  
      <input tags prefilled="product.tags[index]" tags-options="{hiddenTagListName: scope.locale+'_tagList'}" locale="index" class="{{index}} tag tm-input" name="{{ index }}_tags" placeholder="Tags"/>  
       </div>  
  </div>
```

And JS:

```
app.directive('tags', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { prefilled: '=prefilled', locale: '=locale'},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('prefilled', function(prefilled) {
                if(prefilled){
                    angular.forEach(prefilled,function(data){
                        element.tagsManager('pushTag',data);

                    })
                }
                return element.tagsManager(scope.$eval(attrs.tagsOptions));
            })

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap your logic in callback of `$timeout` with zero delay?

Like this:

```
$timeout(function yourLogicHere() {}, 0);
```

This callback should be called after `$digest` cycle, so all data should already been bound to DOM.